# array_diff with calculation

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-difference

Please, consider the following arrays:

```
$reference = array(
    '080604' => 4,
    '080703' => 4,
    '080734' => 2,
    '080819' => 2,
    '088341' => 2,
    '805238' => 20,
    '805283' => 4,
    '805290' => 2,
    '805849' => 2,
    '806051' => 2,
    '806068' => 2,
);

$test = array(
    '080604' => 2,
    '080703' => 4,
    '080819' => 1,
    '088341' => 2,
    '805238' => 20,
    '805283' => 4,
    '805290' => 2,
    '805849' => 2,
    '806051' => 2,
    '806068' => 2,
);
```

They are quite similar, but can have some various differences, e.g. it's possible that:
- some keys of $reference are not present in $test at all
- some keys of $test are not present in $reference at all
- all keys are present, but the values in $reference and $test are different (sometimes $reference value is bigger than $test and sometimes the value of $test is bigger than $reference)

I need to find out the differences automatically and to output them in a way, that not only the difference in count itself, but also a description is provided, e.g.

```
$result = [
   '080604' => [
       'reference' => 4,
       'test' => 2
   ]
];
```

If some value is in only one of the lists:

```
$result = [
   '1234567890' => [
       'reference' => 0,
       'test' => 2
   ]
];
```

or something like that.

Does someone have an idea, which is the best way to accomplish this in an elegant way? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each and populate the array with values if present:

```
$combined = [];

foreach ($reference as $key => $val) {
    $combined[$key] = [
        'test' => 0,
        'reference' => $val,
    ];
}

foreach ($test as $key => $val) {
    if (!isset($combined[$key])) {
        $combined[$key] = [
            'reference' => 0,
            'test' => 0,
        ]
    }

    $combined[$key]['test'] = $val;
}
```

`$combined` will contain both values from both arrays with reference to both the elements from `$reference` and `$test`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$result = array_diff($reference, $test);
print_r($result)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.